# Java: Program terminates after catching InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception

I have a class Player, which contains a function that takes in an integer as a parameter. In my main function, which is in another class called Game, I have section that takes in user input, and passes it into the DoMove(int i) function of the Player class.
In my Game class I have this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Player p1 = new Player();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int entry;
        while(GameNotOver() == true)
        {

            do{
                try
                {
                    p1.DoMove(entry);

                } catch (InputMismatchException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Bad choice!");
                    input.next();
                }
            } while (p1.DoMove(entry) == false);
       }
    }
```

Essentially, the main function is passing in a parameter to another classes function, which works fine. But that parameter is supposed to be an integer. If I type in a bunch of characters and press enter, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
```

The main GameNotOver loop runs fine, and the entire program works perfectly if I omit all of the exception handling.
And the program exits. I think I am not properly catching the exception. Any tips?

Comment: Does `input.next()` also throw `InputMismatchException`? Also, you can debug this on your own with IDEs like Netbeans, Eclipse or IDEA. Give it a try. It's fun.

Comment: Consider what is `TicTacToe.java Line 28`

Comment: `DoMove(b1,entry)` <-- do you have an overloaded version of `DoMove()`?  It would be nice to see what this method is doing.

Comment: A value is never ever assigned to `entry`

Comment: Apologies, I messed up some copying. There is a entry = input.nextInt() above all of this, and the whole thing is running in a loop.

Comment: edit your question with the proper code, and the proper stacktrace

Comment: This code does not call `Scanner.nextInt()`, and therefore does not throw the exception shown. Post the real code, or the real exception. However it makes no sense whatsoever to call `next()` inside the catch block, or to catch `InputMismatchException` after a block that doesn't throw it.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your DoMove method, as this piece of code can not throw the error you are facing. Also, you should not call `input.next` inside the catch block, as it makes no sense. If there is an error in the input, obviously you dont want to try to read it as it's an invalid entry.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is thrown from:

```
p1.DoMove(entry)
```

and then right after processing the exception you do the exact same action:

```
} while (p1.DoMove(entry) == false)
```

Is DoMove(entry) supposed to act differently when it's invoked again with the same input?